# Identifying AMD GPUs

Tags: c++, windows, opencl, amd-gpu

I have trouble telling different GPUs apart. This is my code and as far as I understand, it should return different bus/device/function numbers, however I get the same for all GPUs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{

    cl_platform_id* platformIDs = nullptr;
    cl_uint platformCount = 0;
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformCount);
    platformIDs = new cl_platform_id[platformCount];
    clGetPlatformIDs(platformCount, platformIDs, nullptr);

    for (cl_uint i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
    {
        cl_uint deviceCount;
        clGetDeviceIDs(platformIDs[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, nullptr, &deviceCount);
        cl_device_id* deviceIDs = new cl_device_id[deviceCount];
        clGetDeviceIDs(platformIDs[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, deviceCount, deviceIDs, nullptr);

        for (cl_uint j = 0; j < deviceCount; j++)
        {
            cl_device_topology_amd amdtopo;
            cl_int clret = clGetDeviceInfo(deviceIDs[j], CL_DEVICE_TOPOLOGY_AMD, sizeof(amdtopo), &amdtopo, nullptr);

            std::cout << "platform=" << i << "; device=" << j << "; ";
            if (clret == CL_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (amdtopo.raw.type == CL_DEVICE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_PCIE_AMD)
                {
                    std::cout <<
                        "bus=" << (int)amdtopo.pcie.bus <<
                        "; device=" << (int)amdtopo.pcie.device <<
                        "; function=" << (int)amdtopo.pcie.function <<
                        ";";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "not amd";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "error";
            }

            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get on machine with 12 AMD GPUs:

```
C:\Users\x>gpuid.exe
platform=0; device=0; error
platform=1; device=0; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=1; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=2; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=3; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=4; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=5; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=6; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=7; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=8; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=9; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=10; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
platform=1; device=11; bus=0; device=0; function=1;
```

Comment: Aren't cl_device_id values different? Maybe they are sharing same pci-e bus? Why don't you query vendor names of devices? Won't they contain "amd" or "advanced micro devices"?

Comment: cl_device_id values are different, yes. Alsoquerying vendor does not help because all are amd. What i want to achieve is to map opencl devices to windows "upnp" or any other identifier, so that i can later adjust frequency, fan speed and other things based on opencl device.

Comment: perhaps the problem is [this](https://steemit.com/nicehash/@thegoddessinari/fixed-nicehash-miner-legacy-exe-for-recent-amd-drivers) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in recent amd drivers:
https://community.amd.com/thread/224200